# Is it okay to ask a user to accept my answer?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Asking for someone to accept your Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88535/asking-for-someone-to-accept-your-answer)

If an OP asks a question and I am the only responder, then the OP states as a comment to my answer, "Thanks that was quite helpful." Is it okay etiquette to ask them to accept/+1 my answer? See here for an example:

[Is it correct to say "CMP command is the longest assembly command"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112400/is-it-correct-to-say-cmp-command-is-the-longest-assembly-command/11112423#11112423)

Just don't want to be rude/badform, also though would like some "credit" if I was helpful.

Comment: In case of new user, Yes you should ask him/her to accept the answer, or put a comment like [How to Accept Answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/65088)

Comment: In the case of a new user, the *system* should be the one browbeating him or her into using the site as designed. Leave the rest of us out of it. Commentary about accepting answers is pure noise.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One *polite* comment reminding the asker that they should accept answers that solved their problem wouldn't hurt. Anything other than that and you'd be [setting yourself for trouble](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134069/should-i-accept-wrong-answers-to-boost-my-accept-rate/134070#134070).

Answer (score 7):

If you worry too much about rep, it can sometimes be a little discouraging when you don't get an upvote or an accept. Instead, just focus on doing a good job and the rep will come.

If you gave the question-asker a really great answer that solves his/her problem, he/she ***will mark it as accepted***.  It might not happen that day though, but chances are, eventually, you'll get the green check mark.

In my experience, I have a lot of answers that get accepted weeks after I posted them. I just wait for them to post new questions that show a low accept rate, and wait for other users to say things like "Hey buddy, why dontcha do something about that accept rate", and let the community do the rep whoring for me ;)

Of course, I do the same when I see low accept rates and politely remind question askers that they'll likely get more attention to their question if they go back and accept old answers that helped them.

In my mind, this seems less "grabby" and also gives the question-asker time to really think about what answers to accept.

Comment: You can always trust the Stack Overflow community to rep whore ;)

Comment: I choose to crowdsource my rep whoring. It works better that way! ;)

Comment: Thanks guys for your answers, I appreciate it, yea, I don't want to look like a rep whore but at the same time, kind of feel slighted if i dont even get the +1 bump. It's all good though, I totally do the SO stuff to give back to the same community that usually has the answer I need for some difficult project im working. Thanks guys!

Comment: Ryan, just remember, reputation points don't carry interest. 10 or 15 points is the same whether you earn it today or a month from now. In fact, if you take a break from answering on SO (due to work, etc) and you've answered a lot of questions, you'll notice your rep still increasing as answers get late upvotes and late accepts. The main difference is that it's less stressful to avoid worrying about the rep and just letting it happen at its own pace.